# Salesforce execution order on flow updates

Tags: apex, force.com, process-builder, configuration, customization

All – I am in the process of resolving the issue when Process builder try to update a field and a validation rule stopping that update. Here my question is if we have 10 flow updates, for each flow updates Salesforce will run all the triggers/validation rules? Or it commits all the 10 flow updates as a list and at end it runs the triggers/validation rules. ?

Comment: What is the meaning for 10 flow updates? it is 10 different flows?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 cases:

1. flow with 10 field update actions:
   This will result into re-evaluating triggers/validation only once provided Reevaluate Records in the Process Builder setting is disable.
2. 10 flow with 1 field updates per flow

**Short answer:** Yes, for each flow updates Salesforce will run all the triggers/validation rules.

**Long answer:** Each flow will run in its own contexts and will be unaware about other flows. This will result in re-evaluating triggers/validation rules 10 times. This is something like you are calling 10 distinguish Update statement.

Also take a note about Reevaluate Records in the Process Builder setting which can cause re-evaluating triggers/validation & same flow up-to 5 times.

Ref: 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_advanced_reevaluate.htm&language=en_US&type=0

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm

Comment: Atul - Thank You for your response.  What I mean my 10 field updates is in once (immediate) flow action contains 10 field different field updates. -      
Santanu - FYI!

Comment: Check my updated answers.